# iterating through collection using for loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb

As a new bee in Mongodb i am using a book for reference.In the book a way is discussed to access the elements of a document inside a collection.I am trying the same using the print function instead of a made up function in the book.

```
//code from the book

>db.blog.find()
{
"title" : "My Blog Post",
"content" : "Here's my blog post.",
"date" : "Sat Dec 12 2009 11:23:21 GMT-0500 (EST)"
}
var collections = ["posts", "comments", "authors"];
for (i in collections) {
doStuff(db.blog[collections[i]]);//Instead of doStuff i am using print
}

//but when i write the below code i am not getting what is expect
var collections = ["posts", "comments", "authors"];
for (i in collections) {
print(db.blog[collections[i]]);//Instead of doStuff i am using print
}
```

What i expect as the output:

```
"My Blog Post"
"Here's my blog post."
"Sat Dec 12 2009 11:23:21 GMT-0500 (EST)"
```

What i am getting:

```
foodbar.blog.name
foodbar.blog.content
foodbar.blog.date
```

Comment: Unrelated to your specific problem but pretty important: `for (i ...` is bad practice. Always use `for (var i ...` or even better, `for (const i ...`. You should also probably use the more intuitive `for-of` instead of `for-in`, which has very surprising behavior in some scenarios.

Comment: Actually i am just trying to imitate the author for better understanding.Anyways thanks for the advice.

Comment: Take it or leave it: if that author is suggesting `for (i ...`, that entire tutorial is scrap.

Comment: it's O'RELLY MongoDB The Definitive Guide.Chapter-2,pg 15.